# eclim android list targets command not found

Tags: java, android, vim, eclim

executing

```
:ProjectCreate /path -n android
```

gives

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: no command android list targets found  
while executing command (port: 9091): -editor vim -command android_list_targets
```

Comment: (I'm not at a computer right now and going off memory). Does eclipse support android projects? I don't believe eclim will install the android components if eclipse doesn't support the feature.

Comment: it worked..
i installed some remaining libs from eclipse and it worked

Comment: Can you post your findings as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that is telling you the android command is not found, what you need to do (you're already solved it but for other readers...) is:

- Be sure you have downloaded the android-sdk and path is properly setup (when installing eclim it ask for its path but you can also change it in your .vimrc).
- Be sure 'android' command is available in your system, i.e loaded in your path. (in linux you can type in a terminal "which android" to see if android cmd can be found).

Good luck!